# List of websites/domain name that's registered daily

Tags: domain-registration, database, top-level-domains

I want to know if there is a website that can provide me a list of domain names that is registered on a certain date. For example today or last week thursday? Does that website which can provide me such info exist? I really appreciate it if you can point out that web URL to me. Google is pointing me to different and irrelevant websites. I saw the whois but it don't display a list. Any help?

Comment: You can get a list of all registered domains, dropped domains, and newly registered domains at http://www.domaindatapro.com - also, this service provides you with daily lists of newly registered domain names and their whois contact information: http://www.easywhoispro.com

Answer (score 3):

You can try dailychanges.com, it does provide a list of domain names on a certain day.

However Dailychanges doesn't give access to a relevant search form, so you have to manually type the following url pattern :

```
site:http://www.dailychanges.com/{web hosting company}/{YYYY-MM-DD}
```

For example if you want domain names registered on March 05, 2011 and hosted at gandi.net :

http://www.dailychanges.com/gandi.net/2011-03-05/